# What are the requirements to drive my UK registered car in Europe after Brexit?

Tags: legal, driving, eu, regulations, brexit

I haven't seen a concise list of requirements as to what I need to have in order for me to drive my UK registered car in Europe after Brexit. (after 31st Dec 2020)

I know how strict eg. the german TUV is, compared to what is required for an MOT in the UK - I believe until the UK was still part of the EU, as long as a foreign car had a valid technical / mechanical approval (MOT), it was accepted as safe to drive on any road (with the exception of the ominous stickers on the headlights, not to blind the oncoming traffic - left hand drive vs right hand drive)

Edit: this is about using the car for a one-off recreational return trip - max 1-2 weeks

Comment: I think you are being overly optimistic in assuming that things have been decided and regulated.

Comment: Are you asking about driving it for a short while, during a visit? Or a long while, because you are living there? The question about the TUV makes me think you are living there, in which case the [expatriates.se] site is a better fit.

Comment: @DJClayworth short trip, max 1-2 weeks, will update in main

Comment: Remember that at this time, from January 1st, most people from the UK won’t be allowed into the EU, like all people from countries with high SARS-Cov-2 prevalence outside of the EU. There is currently no date for when this will end and currently no planned exception for the UK (unless I missed something).

Comment: Even before the UK joined the EU cars were allowed to make short visits with the only issue being the headlamp blackers.

Comment: A lot of websites for motoring organisations, car insurance companies, etc, have summaries e.g. https://www.theaa.com/european-breakdown-cover/driving-in-europe/driving-after-brexit

Answer (score 2):

You will need a GB sticker on your car if you don't have the Euro symbol on your plates. From [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/displaying-number-plates/flags-symbols-and-identifiers):

> You’ll still need a GB sticker when travelling in Europe if you
> display one of these national flags and identifiers.
>
> The flag must be above the identifier. You cannot have the flag or
> letters on the number plate margin, and neither can be more than 50
> millimetres wide. Euro symbol
>
> If you display the Euro symbol and Great Britain (GB) national
> identifier on your number plate, then you will not need a separate GB
> sticker when travelling within the European Union.
>
> The Euro symbol must:
>
> - be a minimum height of 98mm
> - have a width between 40 and 50mm
> - have a reflective blue background with 12 reflecting yellow stars at the top
> - show the member state (GB) in reflecting white or yellow

Comment: You may wish to have a sticker anyway, just to be completely safe, in case you decide to drive outside the EU.